# Time Complexity of a recursive function where the base case isn't O(1)

Tags: performance, recursion, time-complexity, fibonacci

Most recursive functions I have seen being asked about (e.g. Fibonacci or Hanoi) have had *O(1)* `return`s, but what would the time complexity be if it wasn't *O(1)* but *O(n)* instead?

For example, a recursive Fibonacci with *O(n)* base case:

```java
class fibonacci { 
    static int fib(int n) { 
      if (n <= 1) 
        for (int i=0;i<n;i++) {
          // something
        }
      return n;
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2); 
    } 
       
    public static void main (String args[]) 
    { 
    int n = 9; 
    System.out.println(fib(n)); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: You would have to count how many times the base case is triggered by `fib(n)`; multiply this count by the complexity of the base case; and add that to your calculation of the complexity. This code for Fibonacci already has a pretty awful complexity; adding `n * (number of calls to fib(0) and fib(1))` is only making it worse.

Comment: The website I nicked this from said that the fibonacci complexity (without the for loop) was O(2^n), what would the complexity of this one be? O(2^n+n*2^n)?

Comment: Yes. Note that O(2^n) is a rough upper bound for the naive implementation of Fibonacci. It's actually Θ(φ^n) ≈ Θ(1.618^n). It would be Θ(2^n) if the two recursive calls were to `fib(n-1)`, but one of them is to `fib(n-2)`, which makes it slightly faster.

Answer (score 2):

The base case for the function that you’ve written here actually still has time complexity *O(1)*. The reason for this is that if the base case triggers here, then *n ≤ 1*, so the `for` loop here will run at most once.

Because so many base cases trigger when the input size is small, it’s comparatively rare to get a base case whose runtime is, say, *O(n)* when the input to the algorithm has size *n*. This would mean that the base case is independent of the array size, which can happen but is somewhat unusual.

A more common occurrence - albeit one I think is still pretty uncommon - would be for a recursive function to have two different parameters to it (say, *n* and *k*), where the recursion reduces *n* but leaves *k* unmodified. For example, imagine taking the code you have here and replacing the `for` loop on *n* in the base case with a `for` loop on *k* in the base case. What happens then?

This turns out to be an interesting question. In the case of this particular problem, it means that the total work done will be given by *O(k)* times the number of base cases triggered, plus *O(1)* times the number of non-base-case recursive calls. For the Fibonacci recursion, the number of base cases triggered computing F<sub>n</sub> is F<sub>n+1</sub> and there are (F<sub>n+1</sub> - 1) non-base-case calls, so the overall runtime would be Θ(k F<sub>n+1</sub> + F<sub>n+1</sub>) = Θ(k φ<sup>n</sup>). For the Towers of Hanoi, you’d similarly see a scaling effect where the overall runtime would be Θ(k 2<sup>n</sup>). But for other recursive functions the runtime might vary in different ways, depending on how those functions were structured.

Hope this helps!